# Can you ssh into an azure sphere MT-3620?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-sphere

Is it possible to connect to some sort of shell on an MT-3620.

I want to be able to see things like top and system performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot SSH into Azure Sphere. 
There is an update regarding [Azure Sphere generally availability in February 2020](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/?p=90017). As per this update, preview of Visual Studio Code extension for Azure Sphere will be available for both Windows and Linux.

Reference: [Plan for changes coming to the Azure Sphere SDK in next release](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Internet-of-Things/Plan-for-changes-coming-to-the-Azure-Sphere-SDK-in-next-release/ba-p/916078)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Understood. There does not seem to be any plans for OS level access. It would be nice to know more about creating services on the device. Like hosting a web interface or lower level access to things like Wi-Fi.